# Permutation Matrices for n = 5

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\sigma \in S_n$ denote the permutation given by
$$
\sigma = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & n \\
n & 1 & 2 & \ldots & n-1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

and let
$$
P = \left(
e^n e^1 e^2 \cdots e^{n-1}
\right) \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}
$$
denote the corresponding permutation matrix.

For $n = 5$ write down the matrices $P^1$, $P^2$, $P^3$, $P^4$ , and $P^5$.

Comment: What does $ P^1$ look like in matrix form?

Comment: This is all I was given.

Comment: $e^k$ looks like the $k$-th standard base vector with the $i$-th component $(e^k)_i = \delta^k_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$
P^1 = P =
\left( e^5 e^1 e^2 e^3 e^4 \right) =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
where $P^k$ is the $k$-th power (matrix multiplication) of $P$, but $e^k$ is the $k$-th canonical base vector.

What has it to do with the permutation $\sigma\in S_5$? Applying it to a vector $x$ gives:
$$
P x =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{matrix}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5 \\
x_1
\end{matrix}
\right) \\
x^t P =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_5, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Once you understand what e.g. $P^3$ means you should be able to calculate it.

Comment: How is the permutation related to the permutation matrix? I understand that both use the independent variable n. Does plugging in n to the permutation (I don't know how to write its symbol) give 1 2 3 4 5 for the first row and 5 1 2 3 4 for the second row?

Comment: $P = (e^{\sigma(1)}, e^{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, e^{\sigma(n)})$ permutates vector components according to the permutation $\sigma : \{ 1,\ldots, n\} \mapsto \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$.

Comment: Could you please show me how to find $P^{1}$ in detail? I think from there I will be capable of find the other four.

Comment: Please note that $P^1 = P$, $P^2 = P P$ etc. You already stated $P$ in the question as a tuple of column vectors, I expanded those column vectors to give you the full matrix of $P$. Please compare the columns of that matrix with the definition from the question, e.g. first column of the matrix is $e^n = e^5$ as $n=5$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Should be easy now.